# How to get full URL from friendly URL

Tags: managed-navigation

I have a method, that uses `SPWeb.GetFile(url)`. When we use Managed Navigation, I have a friendly URL and `GetFile(friendlyUrl)` doesn't work:

```
Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

How can I get the full Url (like 'http://mysite/Pages/allproducts.aspx') from a friendly URL (like 'http://mysite/products')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function

```
public string GetPageUrl(string friendlyUrl) {       
    //current web
    SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;   
    //check if the current web is a publishing weg
    if (PublishingWeb.IsPublishingWeb(web)) {    
        //get the pages list id
        Guid listId = PublishingWeb.GetPagesListId(web);     
        //retrieve the pages list
        SPList pagesList = web.Lists[listId];    
        //itterate trough the pages
        foreach (SPListItem item in pagesList.Items) {
            //retrieve the terms used for the navigation (this can be multiple terms)
            IList<NavigationTerm> terms = TaxonomyNavigation.GetFriendlyUrlsForListItem(item, false);
            //check if the pages has terms associated with it
            if (terms.Count > 0) {
                //use the GetResolvedDisplayUrl to retrieve the page friendly urls
                if(terms[0].GetResolvedDisplayUrl(string.Empty).ToLower() == friendlyUrl.ToLower())
                    return item.File.Url;
            } 
        }
    }
    return friendlyUrl;
}
```

Comment: Nice to hear that.